# Amazon elastic beanstalk losing db on deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've an rails application running on amazon elastic beanstalk, but every time that I deploy using `$ eb deploy` I lost all my data.

It's a simple application and I'm using rails default database, sqlite, is there any way to fix this without migrate my database to MySQL?

Please, can someone help me?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application needs to be stateless. If you want to preserve data without migrating to rds you can look at EFS(Elastic File System)